# php_browscap.ini file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project and I want to save the user log in which I have to save users browser name and OS. I am using get_browser function. I downloaded the php_browscap.ini file. where I have to keep this file and what changes I have to make in my php.ini file so that get_browser works properly

Thanks in advance

Comment: if u cannot answer or dont wana ans why you vote

Comment: I suspect you've been downvoted as this information is easily searchable - as well as being available on the PHP site. I tend to think it is a good idea to avoid chat/text speak as well, so as to make questions more readable for everyone.

Comment: I tried ist i downloaded the file i cahnged the path in my php.ini file but its still not working for me thats why i asked it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually tricky to configure php.ini to achieve get_browser() works seamlessly.

I'd recommend not reinvent a wheel and just use nice project phpbrowsecap (available at https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap). It's not my project, but I use it in my personal project and just works! :)

Additional benefit is that is periodically automatically updates browsecap (and caches it locally).